# Create new window that is always on top

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a pop-up window in Excel using VBA. Creating the window and setting the size and position works as expected.

Is there a way to make the window always stay on top?

```vb
' some snippets from the code, not complete
' ******************************************

' Creating the now window 
ActiveWindow.NewWindow

' Setting the sizeand position of the pop-up window
With ActiveWindow  
    .WindowState = xlNormal
    .Top = Application.UsableWidth * 0.2
    .Left = Application.UsableWidth * 0.5
    .Height = Application.UsableHeight * 0.5
    .Width = Application.UsableWidth * 0.25
End With
```

Comment: What is the idea of having an Excel Window on Top of other Excel Windows? As a user, I would find this annoying. And how do you want to prevent that this window is closed again?

Comment: Exactly, the user would be allowed to close it again, that's no problem.
I agree, the concept is not ideal; Excel isn't the right tool for what we are trying to do; however, I have no choice.

Comment: But what is the idea? Wouldn't a Userform  not be the better alternative?

Comment: I actually don't know, I was just asked to solve this specific task.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot understand the reason, but you can accomplish what you try in the next way:

1. Please, copy the next API declaration on top of a standard module (in the declarations area):

```
 Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowPos _
         Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As LongPtr, _
                      ByVal X As Long, ByVal Y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, _
                      ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
```

2. Please, copy the next code in the same standard module and run it:

```
Sub testNewWindowOnTop()
    Dim W As Window, wHwnd As LongPtr
     Const HWND_TOPMOST = -1
     Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1, SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
     Const FLAGS As Long = SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOSIZE
    
    Set W = ActiveWindow.NewWindow 'need the object to extract its handle
    
    With W
       .WindowState = xlNormal
       .Top = Application.UsableWidth * 0.2
       .Left = Application.UsableWidth * 0.5
       .Height = Application.UsableHeight * 0.5
       .Width = Application.UsableWidth * 0.25
    End With
    
    SetWindowPos CLngPtr(W.hwnd), HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, FLAGS
End Sub
```

I used the window dimensions you try using, but they look strange to me...

It works for 64 bit installations, but it can be easily adapted to work for both cases (32 and 64 bit)...

If you need the window to not be on Top, anymore, you should call the API using

```
Const HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
```

Of course, `wHwnd` should be declared on Top of the module, to be valid for both cases (`Private wHwnd As LongPtr`)...

Comment: @KasparJohannes Didn't you find some time to test the above code? In the meantime, somebody voted it down... Doesn't it work as you need?